# Lines of Action board with recursive

Tags: java, recursion

I have been trying to make a Lines of Action board with recursive. I have already done the multidimensional array (8x8). Now, the only problem I have is how to put the pieces in their correct place (especially the black ones). What's my problem? when I'm trying to print the first row of the pieces it prints something like this: `"-b-b-b-b-b--"`, instead of `"-bbbbbb-"`. This is also true for the last row.

```
public static void im (int[][]m, int r, int c){//Matriz
    if (r==m.length-1 && c==m[0].length-1) {
        System.out.print("-");
    } else {
        if(r==0 && c>0 && c<m[0].length-1){
            System.out.print("b");
        }
        if(c==0 && r>0 && r<m.length-1){
            System.out.print("w");
        }
        if (c==m[0].length-1) {
            if(r>0){
                System.out.print("w");
                System.out.println("");
                im(m,r+1,0);
            }else{
                System.out.print("-");
                System.out.println("");
                im(m,r+1,0);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.print("-");
            im(m,r,c+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in your if-statements is flawed, you could try again and comment in every block what you know upto now. Like this:

```
if (a) {
    // I know that a == true
    if (b) {
        // I know that a == true && b == true
    } else {
        // I know that a == true && b == false
    }
}
```

This way you can easily spot the mistakes yourself, if this doesn't help just comment and I'll reply the correct code.

**EDIT:** Here is the correct code:

```
if (r == 0 || r == m[0].length - 1) {
    // top or bottom row
    if (c == 0 || c == m.length - 1) {
        // top or bottom row and leftmost column or rightmost column
        System.out.print("-");
    } else {
        // top or bottom row and not leftmost column or rightmost column
        System.out.print("b");
    }
} else {
    // not top or bottom row
    if (c == 0 || c == m.length - 1) {
        // not top or bottom row and leftmost column or rightmost column
        System.out.print("w");
    } else {
        // not top or bottom row and not leftmost column or rightmost column
        System.out.print("-");
    }
}
```

I don't really know how to fix your original code since it doesn't really make sense to me, so I just completely rewrote it, a good thing to remember is that you want every function call to output only 1 character so at least try to gaurantee that it can only reach one of the print statements at a time.

**EDIT2:**

```
public static void im(int[][] m, int r, int c) {
    if (r == 0 || r == m.length - 1) {
        // top or bottom row
        if (c == 0 || c == m[0].length - 1) {
            // top or bottom row and leftmost column or rightmost column
            System.out.print("-");
        } else {
            // top or bottom row and not leftmost column or rightmost column
            System.out.print("b");
        }
    } else {
        // not top or bottom row
        if (c == 0 || c == m[0].length - 1) {
            // not top or bottom row and leftmost column or rightmost column
            System.out.print("w");
        } else {
            // not top or bottom row and not leftmost column or rightmost column
            System.out.print("-");
        }
    }
    if (c == m[0].length - 1) {
        // rightmost column
        System.out.println();
        if (r != m.length - 1) {
            // not bottom row
            im(m, r + 1, 0);
        }
    } else {
        // not rightmost column
        im(m, r, c + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see the problem. Was it a mistake that I started doing it by columns (white pieces only) instead of rows?

Comment: I hven't tried the code yet, but what I'm afraid of is that this is not a recursive code. Nonetheless, your code seems "cleaner" than mine meaning that I'm going to try it and make it recursive. I'm going to tell you later how it went. Thank you!

Comment: Oh sorry only now realised the recursion, I'll edit in a recursive version.

Comment: Thank you! It worked :) I'm going to study your code over and over again. By the way, thanks for documentating!